# How to set host environment variables inside npm scripts(package.json)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

Imagine I have an environment variable

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

when I do

```
echo $NODE_ENV //--> shows production which is correct
```

**Problem:**

Inside my package.json

```
scripts: {
...
"build": "export REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development}; 
          npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
...
}
```

Now when I do `npm run build` REACT_APP_NODE_ENV is getting set to development...but it should have been production as NODE_ENV is present.

If I do

```
scripts: {
...
"build": "export REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=production; 
   npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
...
}
```

It works correctly as expected i.e. all scripts access the REACT_APP_NODE_ENV with expected value that is production.

**Goal**

I wish to avoid hardcoding in my package.json

How can I set *REACT_APP_NODE_ENV* with value `${NODE_ENV}`

```
"build": "export REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}; 
  npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to ensure that this is cross-platform which will save you some headaches later on.

That problem has already been solved in the npm package [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var).

Then, assuming you've already exported NODE_ENV, you use it this way:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i am not looking for across OS solution.
I am saying this does not work `"build": "export REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}; 
  npm run build-css && react-scripts build",` the NODE_ENV does not get set to REACT_APP_NODE_ENV